# C# Download/Read log file from FTP

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I have a few `.log` files on an FTP server. I need to download them on my drive. Alternatively, read and display contents. I've read related posts here, and came up with the code: 
**DOWNLOAD**

```
public void DownloadFile(String infile)

    {
        String myUrl = String.Format("ftp://{0}/{1}", IpAddress, infile);

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(myUrl));
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        String output = String.Format("{0}", infile);
        using (StreamWriter destination = new StreamWriter(output))
        {
            destination.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
            destination.Flush();
        }

        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
```

**READ**

```
public string ReadTxtFile2(String infile)
    {
        WebClient request = new WebClient();
        String url = String.Format("ftp://{0}/{1}", IpAddress, infile);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
        try
        {
            // also tried: String fileString = request.DownloadString(url);

            byte[] newFileData = request.DownloadData(url);
            string fileString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);
            return fileString;
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
```

Somehow the download returns me an empty 0 kb file and a read() function outputs an empty contents. I can't find out why, any help?
**NOTE:** files do exist on server, I can list them.

Comment: Did you chekc the responses? Does `response` have an error status? Did you get an exception in the second snippet? BTW both snippets do the same thing. WebClient uses an FtpWebRequest internally. Both retrieve the entire contents of the file. The only difference is that one of the snippets returns them as a string while the other writes them in a roundabout way - it could have just used `responseStream.CopyTo(someFileStream)`. You could have returned a string from the FtpWebRequest snippet if you used a StreamReader to read the file's contents

Comment: There's no error and no exception. I also tried `CopyTo` method outcome is the same.